# MongoDB DISTINCT/UNIQUE Values Count without using countDocuments() or distinct() [mongoose, node]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, count, distinct

In MongoDB, Is there any way I can do UNIQUE COUNT?

1. countDocuments() will not work in my case
2. find().count() will not work in my case
3. After finding result, arr.length() will not work in my case.
4. countDocuments().distinct('fieldName').length() will not work in my case.
5. find().distinct().length will not work in my case.

Note: Already using aggregation pipeline according my needs but query is a bit slower as there are so many counts.

My aggregation pipeline example:

```
{ 
  $match: {
        isSent: true,
        documentStatus: 'Sent',
}},
{
  $group: {
         _id: '$documentId',
}},
{
  $group: {
         _id: 1,
         count: { $sum: 1 },
}}
```

Just like this, there are around 7-8 counters that I need and they all are taking some time to be calculated due to my distinction with documentId but that's my requirement.

P.S. -> We **CAN NOT USE** above mentioned methods as they're all will dump data into memory and then simply array.length will be peformed, so consider millions of records, these find().length(), distinct('documentId').length() won't work as node server will crash due to less amount of RAM/Memory.

Comment: the db.distinct("").length is the best you can do, I don't think there's a way to do the distinct count in the db and only return the number to the server without using aggregation

Comment: @alkhatim That's why I mentioned that distinct().length() will not work as it will cost so much memory when records are in millions. It's not efficient way for me.

Comment: The aggregate approach would be the correct way. You can improve the performance by defining an index on the fields used in the aggregate''s `$match` stage. Aggregate distinct is a stateful and blocking operation - it is resource intensive (you cannot avoid it).

Comment: @prasad_ Already added indexes on required fields! Although, thanks for the resource intensive information, I didn't know that.

Comment: I am sure you are already aware, that the aggregate runs totally on the database server.

Comment: @prasad_ yes. But, my issue is time consumption. Can we improvise that time ? Or can you help me with another logical solution ?

Comment: If you create a compound index on isSent, documentStatus, and documentId, you should be able to get the query to be covered, which will save the time of reading all of the documents from disk.